# User-specified csv reading and printing in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a script that should read in a user-specified 2-column csv file located in the same directory, do some maths on the data, and print the results out to stdout which is another user-defined csv file. I made it in 2.7.5 but now having just finally moved over to 3.2, it doesn't work.  Not a shock I know but I'm pretty inexperienced in programming and I'm having trouble working out how to make it work in Python 3.

I've stripped back the code to its basic reading and printing elements that used to work and it still isn't working in 3.2 despite doing some of the more obvious modifications, it just gets stuck and never prints to the new file. I have tried using 2to3.py but it throws up a bad input parseerror and no changes are made!  I'd rather learn exactly why it now doesn't work anyway.

The type of command I want is;

```
somedirectory>myscript inputdata.csv > outputdata.csv
```

Here's a stripped-back version of the Python 2.7.5 script that worked so you can see what i am doing, (I have left in all the imports)

```python
import fileinput, math, sys, numpy as np
from numpy import linspace, loadtxt, ones, convolve
from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    parser = OptionParser() 
    options,args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        data = [(line.rstrip()).split(',') for line in fileinput.input(args)]
    except IOError as detail:
        print >> sys.stderr, detail
        sys.exit(2)

    '''kept these lines in just to make sure the data is in the same format as when it worked before'''
    t = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
    m = [float(row[1]) for row in data]
    result = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(t, m)]

    for line in result:
        print >> sys.stdout, str(line[0]) + ',' + str(line[1])

options = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Obviously Print is now a function, deprecated Optparse can be converted over to Argparse etc

so I thought something like this would be fine,

```python
import fileinput, math, sys, inspect, numpy as np
from numpy import linspace, loadtxt, ones, convolve
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()   
    options,args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        data = [(line.rstrip()).split(',') for line in fileinput.input(args)]
    except IOError as detail:
        print(detail, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(2)

    '''kept these lines in just to make sure the data is in the same format as when it worked before'''
    t = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
    m = [float(row[1]) for row in data]
    result = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(t, m)]

    for line in result:
        print(str(line[0]) + ',' + str(line[1]), file=sys.stdout)

options = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There are probably some glaring issues with this but after researching all the elements I'm stuck on where exactly it's breaking.

Additionally there are probably better ways of doing this type of csv-file reading and writing, i just stuck with this as I know it *did* work. I know about the csv module for example, but i cannot find any examples of using it on user-specified files from command line like how i need it, all the examples I can find define the file to be opened in the script itself.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things before the code. If you use the `argparse` module you, you have to specify that it has to receive a filename as input. This is what I did with the `add_argument`. Since the argument is not optional the application will exit if the user does not specify the filename.

If the user specified the filename I try to open it and create a csv reader. csv reader is just an iterator that parsed the file so I can iterate through every row, which I do and populate the resulting list. When the list is populated the application iterates through the list printing out all the elements. `try/except` is there incase anything went wrong.

```
import io
import csv
import argparse

def main():
    # Create the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='Name of the file you want to load')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    result = []
    with io.open(args.filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            result.append([row[0], row[1]])

    for item in result:
        print('{0}, {1}'.format(*item))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Something went wrong {0}'.format(e))
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks a lot more like how it should be done! However i can't seem to get this code to work.  If I don't use argparse and change the object in the io.open() to a specific filename this runs fine, but when I use as above I get "error: to few arguments" when using a command in command line in the format i gave above.  It should work as it is the same format as the usage states. In fact no matter how i try it it doesn't seem to recognise any input file I call.  How should you call the input file in command for this?

Comment: You don't have to change anything just save it to `myscript.py` and call it as you stated in you question: `python myscript.py inputdata.csv > outputdata.csv`

Comment: Thank you, after some playing about I just found this out too. That's not exactly the command I stated. With the old code I would change directory to the location of my script and csv's, `CD C:\somedirectory`, and type the command `myscript inputdata.csv > outputdata.csv`. Now i need to specify "python" and the extension of the python script, not exactly what i was looking for but at least it now works!

Comment: Are you on linux or windows?

Comment: Can you copy the output of `echo %PATHEXT%`

Comment: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw

Comment: OK, now just to check if the Python3 is in the path. Give me `echo %PATH%` and tell me where have you installed Python3.

Comment: If Python3 is in the path then everything should work ok. You could just run your script with `myscript inputdata.csv > outputdata.csv` in the directory where your script is.

Comment: C:\Python32\ and C:\Python32\Scripts are in the path, this is where i installed the new python version to.

Comment: Ah so you have both python2 and python3 installed. Ok then just add `#! python3` as the first line of the file and everything should work ok.

Comment: I uninstalled 2.7 and it is no longer in the path, `#! python3` makes no change.

Comment: OK to wrap it up :) 1. the script works, you can run it with python and everything works OK. 2. `PATHEXT` conains `.py` and `.pyw` so you should be able to run the script just by typing `yourscript` without the extension. 3. Python is in path. 4. The only problem I could think of is that `*.py` files are not associated with the python interpreter. So, either associate them with `python.exe` or reinstall python3 and the installation will do that for you (assuming you use the official python msi installation).

Answer (score 0):

This `main` works, just changing the `print`:

```
def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    options,args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        data = [(line.rstrip()).split(',') for line in fileinput.input(args)]
    except IOError as detail:
        print(detail, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(2)

    '''kept these lines in just to make sure the data is in the same format as when it worked before'''
    t = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
    m = [float(row[1]) for row in data]
    result = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(t, m)]

    for line in result:
        print(', '.join(str(x) for x in line), file=sys.stdout)
```

---

The reason you don't get anything from the 2nd version is the indent on `sys.exit(2)`

```
except IOError as detail:
    print(detail, file=sys.stderr)
sys.exit(2)
```

It exits without moving on to the normal output

With corrections to argparse (allowing 1 or more input files):

```
def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infiles',nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        data = [(line.rstrip()).split(',') for line in fileinput.input(args.infiles)]
    except IOError as detail:
        print(detail, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(2)

    '''kept these lines in just to make sure the data is in the same format as when it worked before'''
    t = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
    m = [float(row[1]) for row in data]
    result = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(t, m)]

    for line in result:
        print(', '.join(str(x) for x in line))
```

Or you can let `argparse` take care of opening the file(s) (and raising an error if needed):

```
import argparse
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infiles',nargs='+', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    data = [row for file in args.infile for row in csv.reader(file)]

    '''kept these lines in just to make sure the data is in the same format as when it worked before'''
    t = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
    m = [float(row[1]) for row in data]
    result = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(t, m)]

    for line in result:
        print(', '.join(str(x) for x in line))
```

`FileType` also recognizes `'-'` as `stdin` (or for a `('w')` file, `stdout`)

Comment: Sorry, with sys.exit(2) this is just an error in formatting in my question, it is correct in the actual script I ran. Thanks for the answer though as per my reply to Victor these still don't seem to work, likely something wrong my end! If i use the first version of main() the script just hangs and doesn't exit. If i use the second I get the same "_error:too few arguments_" as with Victor's answer (the issues here must be something to do with argparse).  With the third bizarrely I get "_NameError: global name 'argparse' is not defined_"!

Comment: `global name 'argparse' is not defined` just means that `argparse` was not imported.  I switched to `argparse.ArgumentParser` because I was also using `argparse.FileType`.

Comment: Sometimes I add `print sys.argv` to see the strings that `argparse` works with.  Normally that should be `['scriptname.py','arg1','arg2',...].  `argparse` uses `sys.argv[1:]`, everything but that 1st one.  `sys.argv[0]` is used as the default `prog` value (in the usage message).